# Traefik Docker Swarm Basic Authentication

Tags: docker, traefik

I recently set up Traefik v.1.7.14 in a Docker container, on a Docker Swarm enabled cluster. As a test, I created a simple service:

```
docker service create --name demo-nginx \
--network traefik-net \
--label traefik.app.port=80 \
--label traefik.app.frontend.auth.basic="test:$$apr1$$LG8ly.Y1$$1J9m2sDXimLGaCSlO8.T20" \
--label traefik.app.frontend.rule="Host:t.myurl.com" \
nginx
```

As the code above states, I am simply installing nginx on my url, at the subdomain `t` specified.

When this code runs, the service gets created successfully. Traefik also shows the service in the traefik api, as well as within the traefik administrator.

In the traefik api, the back-end service is reported as follows:

```
"frontend-Host-t-myurl-com-0": {
"entryPoints": [
"http",
"https"
],
"backend": "backend-demo-nginx",
"routes": {
"route-frontend-Host-t-myurl-com-0": {
"rule": "Host:t.myurl.com"
}
},
"passHostHeader": true,
"priority": 0,
"basicAuth": null,
"auth": {
"basic": {}
}
```

When I go to visit `t.myurl.com`, I get the authentication prompt, as expected.

However, when I type in my username/password (test:test, in this case),  the login prompt just prompts me again and doesn't authenticate me.

I have checked to ensure that I am escaping the characters in the docker label by using:

```
echo $(htpasswd -nb test test) | sed -e s/\\$/\\$\\$/g
```

To generate the password.

As part of my testing, I also tried turning off the **https** entryPoint, as I wanted to see if this cycle was somehow being triggered by ssl. That didn't seem to have any impact on resolving this (rule: `--label traefik.app.frontend.entryPoints=http`). Traefik did properly respond on `http` upon doing this, but the password authentication still fell into the same prompting loop as before.

When I remove the `traefik.app.frontend.auth.basic` label, I can access my site at my url (t.myurl.com). So this issue appears to be isolated within the basic authentication functionality.

My DNS provider is Cloudflare.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Can you try to replace `traefik.app.frontend.auth.basic` with `traefik.app.frontend.auth.basic.users`? the first one is deprecated

Comment: Hey zochamx, thank you for your comment. I tried replacing the `traefik.app.frontend.auth.basic` with your recommendation. I still get the same login prompt.  I also ran the echo command again with test test (usr/pwd... just to be 100% sure that I was starting fresh). None of this seemed to have any impact. The password is still not accepted.

Comment: Hmm I just noticed sth else. Can you do a `docker inspect <your nginx service id>` and check the value of your label ? Is that the proper password? I am sure that the `$` sign needs to be escaped inside compose file though I have my doubts for the command line service creation command.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
echo $(htpasswd -nb your-user your-password);
```

Because you don't need two `$$` in the command line.